# Passing values through activities

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I made some app, that you can create account with it, and it's passing username and his password, although username get's passed without any problem, I cant pass the password, it's nummeric password edittext view, and i know that, like program reads the value, but it doesn't pass it to another activity.

1st activity, setting and reading the password, everything is ok till there:

```
     public void nowekonto(View view){
    final Intent intent1 = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    Intent intent4 = new Intent(this, proszenieohaslo.class );
    EditText nazwauzytkownika = findViewById(R.id.nazwauz);
    EditText haslonum = findViewById(R.id.edithaslo);//numeric password 
    String haslo1 = haslonum.getText().toString();
    String nazwa1 = nazwauzytkownika.getText().toString();
    Toast zapisano = Toast.makeText(context, haslo1, toastduration);
    zapisano.show();//shows the password typed in edittext
    intent1.putExtra("nazwauz", nazwa1);//this gets passed normally
    intent4.putExtra("haslouz1", haslo1);//probably doesn't pass here
```

2nd activity where password should get passed :

```
  Intent intent2 = new Intent(this, stronaglowna.class);
    Intent intent4 = getIntent();
    EditText haslo = findViewById(R.id.proszenieohaslo);
    String haslopodane = haslo.getText().toString();
    String haslozapisane = getIntent().getStringExtra("haslouz1");// no value
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you only need 1 intent to pass the values.

Source activity:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, SourceActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("username","nazwa1");
    intent.putExtra("password","haslo1");
    startActivity(intent);
```

Destination activity(Inside onCreate):

```
    userName = getIntent().getStringExtra("username");
    passWord = getIntent().getStringExtra("password");
```

[Start another activity documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity)

Answer (score 0):

```
intent1.putExtra("haslouz1", haslo1);
```

Use your `intent1` instead `intent4`. You can use only one intent to launch an activity and transfer data. I assume you use `intent1` to launch the activity but you put your password into `intent4` which is not used for launching anything.

Comment: Changed it, but still nothing. I use intent1 to start and it goes to main activity, but the password-cheking is in another activity, and it still shows no value

Comment: @PiotrSzkudlarek How do you check the password in another activity if you don't launch it?

Comment: I launch it from main activity

Comment: Oh, i think i know now, i have to pass it from main activity, not the second?

Comment: @PiotrSzkudlarek from your code I don't see clearly which activity is Main and which is the second one. But you can use one intent to launch only one activity, and data in that intent will be available only in the launched activity and nowhere else.